# How to output a value of an other table from an indexed field in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, join, session-variables

I have two MySQL tables

1. users with id, user_formOfAdress and serveral additional fields. Field user_formOfAdress contains the id of table formofadress
2. formofadress with id, formOfAdress_german and serveral additional fields, for example id 1 = Mr., id 2 = Mrs.

The record of the users table is identified by a Session variable.

To output not the id of the field user_formOfAdress but the value of the table formofadress.formOfAdress_german (for example Mr. or Mrs.) I have written this:

```
if(array_key_exists("id", $_SESSION) && $_SESSION['id']){
        $uid = $_SESSION['id'];
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost:3307", "root", "Dinah123", "proficrm");
        $query = "
        SELECT formofadress.ID AS formofadress_ID, formofadress.formOfAdress_german, users.ID, users.user_formOfAdress 
        FROM `formofadress` 
        LEFT JOIN users 
        ON formofadress.formofadress_ID = users.user_formOfAdress
        WHERE `users.ID` = '".$uid."' 
        LIMIT 1
        ";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
    $user_formOfAdress = $record['formOfAdress_german'];
        }
```

"FROM formofadress" because I want to output the Mr. or Mrs. of this table, but I have to use also the users table because of the Session ID which is also the id of the users record ...

Not every record in the users table has a value in user_formOfdAdress (value 1, 2 or NULL) but every record in the formofadress table has a fixed value.

Error is:
Undefined variable: user_formOfAdress located in the last row

It's my first time to use JOINs and I'm unfortunately not able to solve this issue even after a long time of searching.

Correct code:

```
if(array_key_exists("id", $_SESSION) && $_SESSION['id']){
        $uid = $_SESSION['id'];
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost:3307", "root", "Dinah123", "proficrm");
        $query = "
            SELECT formofadress.ID, formofadress.formOfAdress_german, users.ID, users.user_formOfAdress 
            FROM formofadress 
            LEFT JOIN users 
            ON formofadress.ID = users.user_formOfAdress 
            WHERE users.ID = '".$uid."' 
        ";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
        $user_formOfAdress = $record['formOfAdress_german'];
    }
```

Comment: Are you certain about your spelling...?

Comment: What is the point of using `while` loop when you LIMIT the result to 1?

Comment: No, I'm not a native english speaker ... but I'm aware about the address should be not "adress", but it's existing in too much code and the database ;-)

Comment: @DinukaD: It's a copy and paste from the existing code for the "normal" not indexed output of several tables

Comment: First, `$user_formOfAdress = $record[formofadress.formOfAdress_german]` should be `$user_formOfAdress = $record['formofadress.formOfAdress_german']`.   Second, user_formOfAdress is not used except in the SQL query. So you must have other code which is not posted here and contains error.

Comment: check if your `formofadress` is really `formOfAdress`. MySQL is case sensitive

Comment: Remove the `while` loop and put `$record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$user_formOfAdress = $record['formOfAdress_german'];` and retry.

Comment: @Phil: thank you, after a lot of trying I have forgotten to correct this, but it's unfortunately not the complete solution ... (I've corrected this, thank you!)

Comment: @Phil: user_formOfAdress is used in the last line to define the variable $user_formOfAdress which is used to output the content in the HTML-Tag

Comment: @Ivan86: formofadress is the the MySQL list. formOfAdress_german is the field description in the formofadress table (varchar) and user_formOfAdress is the field description in the users table (int = index of the formofadress table)

Comment: I mean the problem is not at that location.  We all see you have define the variable here. So the problem should be another position and there may be error in your SQL query, so ` $user_formOfAdress = $record['formofadress.formOfAdress_german'];`  is not executed.

Comment: @DinukaD: Thank you, now the error is solved but the output is empty although there is a value in the users table and a record in the formofadress table ...

Comment: Please check JOIN key data structures. Since you haven't publish it cannot give an exact answer. Also check `$uid` has a value match with table record.

Comment: Yes, record with this user id is existing and $uid is existing and functioning in all the other outputs. users.user_formOfAdress value is 1 for this record, formofadress.formofadress_ID with value 1 is "Herr" (german for Mr.) in the field formofadress.formOfAdress_german. Actual output unfortunately is empty ... no error message anymore

Comment: When changing FROM formofadress LEFT JOIN users and visa versa I always get the echo value 1 what brings me to the question if $record['formOfAdress_german'] could be include a value when not being an array any more after replacing my mysqli_fetch_array from the beginning ...

Comment: I tested the query in phpMyAdmin and ... I had to remove the ` before and after my fieldnames to make it running. Now I have the right value imported ... but the drop-down-selection is gone, which has to be solved now as well the storage of the selected value to the database (which was functioning before ... with the selection values 1 and 2 to the users table. Thank you for your help. Please, could you uprate your comments Ivan86 and DinukaD - I'm not allowed to do this as a greenhorn here. Thank you for your kindly effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were problems with your `SQL` syntax. You used `LEFT JOIN` to join `users` to `formofadress` while `users` sometimes can't follow and you will possibly get a `NULL` value. I also cleaned up your other query syntax so it is more readable.

Also, check to see if the database is expecting an `INT` for `$uid`. If not then return the apostrophes `''`.

```
if(array_key_exists("id", $_SESSION) && $_SESSION['id'])
{
    $uid = $_SESSION['id'];
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost:3307", "root", "Dinah123", "proficrm");
    $query = "SELECT u.ID, u.user_formOfAdress, f.ID, f.formOfAdress_german,  
    FROM users u LEFT JOIN formofadress f ON f.formofadress_ID = u.user_formOfAdress 
    WHERE u.ID = ".$uid." LIMIT 1";
    // if database is not expecting `INT` for `u.ID` then return the apostrophes ' '

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    // mysqli_fetch_assoc returns case sensitive keys
    $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $user_formOfAdress = $record['formOfAdress_german'];
 }
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array()` returns both associative and numeric arrays. If you want get precisely an associative array please use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

Comment: Thank you Ivan86. I have to use the mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) to reach my goal. I'm updating the code above.

Comment: @DinukaD: Thank you, now the error is solved but the output is empty although there is a value in the users table and a record in the formofadress table ...

Comment: Could it be the WHERE `users.ID` = '".$uid."'? I have no idea how to combine the output of formofadress.formOfAdress_german with usage of the Session ID to select the right record in the users table ... . When using the Session ID I should use FROM users but when to output the formofadress.formOfAdress_german I have to use FROM formofadress ...

Comment: @DinukaD You are right, `mysqli_fetch_array()` does take `MYSQLI_BOTH` as it's default option, totally forgot about that. Given he says everything else is OK I thought there might be a problem with his index naming.

Comment: If the `users.ID` is an `int` please use `users.ID = ".$uid." `. If it's a string please use `users.ID = '".$uid."'`.

Comment: @GerdMarinelli I updated, try this code, I think you had problems with your `JOIN` being set up the other way around.

Comment: users.ID is an INT. When making an echo of $record it returns a 1 instead of Herr (german translation for Mr.) but showing nothing in the HTLM Tag with the value="<?php echo $user_formOfAdress; ?>" where there was shown the index 1 before using the LEFT JOIN SQL-option

Comment: @GerdMarinelli It would be easier if you set up a sample [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). We would solve it in a second then. The problem is the query.

Comment: @GerdMarinelli did you try my recent code changes? I think it should work now. If not, please set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) so we can all save time. You don't need to make the all the tables with all the columns and all the rows. Just two tables and enough columns and rows to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @GerdMarinelli I had a typo in the last line of the code, its not `$record['f.formOfAdress_german'];` it's `$record['formOfAdress_german'];`. I edited to include the correction. And why not just use `localhost` instead of `localhost:3307` in your database connection?

Comment: localhost:3307 because it's a MariaDB and yes, I try to settle up the SQL fiddle. And yes, I made all the suggested changes.

Comment: When changing FROM formofadress LEFT JOIN users and visa versa as suggested from Inuka I always get the echo value 1 what brings me to the question if $record['formOfAdress_german'] could be include a value when not being an array any more after replacing my mysqli_fetch_array from the beginning ...

Comment: @GerdMarinelli OK, nice. We will know what is wrong when we see the fiddle. If you need any help setting it up just ask, I can provide you example `create table` and `insert table` instructions to speed up the process if you need them.

Comment: I tested the query in phpMyAdmin and ... I had to remove the ` before and after my `fieldnames` to make it running. Now I have the right value imported ... but the drop-down-selection is gone, which has to be solved now as well the storage of the selected value to the database (which was functioning before ... with the selection values 1 and 2 to the users table. Thank you for your help. Please, could you uprate your comments Ivan86 and DinukaD - I'm not allowed to do this as a greenhorn here. Thank you for your kindly effort!

Comment: @GerdMarinelli Please post the code that contains the `drop-down-selection` you are talking about. So this line of code `$user_formOfAdress = $record['formOfAdress_german'];` gets the correct value? That is solved?

Comment: @Ivan86: Yes all is solved, thank you! I've solved the drop-down and saving of the result into the database with a Session variable to use it in an external ajax file.

Comment: @GerdMarinelli very nice, I'm glad you solved it. Peace